# Math calculations using Awk on dynamic rows

Tags: awk

I have a sample file with values like below, and I want to calculate weighted average on the parts within []

```
6708.1717,07/15/2015,[6708:2],[6708.1609:3],[6708.5:5]
3352.130000000,07/15/2015,[3352:4]
6708.1717,07/15/2015,[6708:2],[6708.1609:2],[6708.5:5]
```

Example output of the first line should be -

```
6708.1717,07/15/2015, [(6708 x 2 + 6708.1609 x 3 + 6708.5 x 5)/2+3+5]
```

The number of columns with [] varies each line.
Is there a way I can use `awk` to calculate

Comment: yes there is a way.

Answer (score 3):

I would write

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{
  n=0
  sum=0
  for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) {
    split( substr( $i, 2, length($i)-2 ), a, /:/)
    sum += a[1]*a[2]
    n += a[2]
  }
  print $1, $2, sum/n
}' file
```

which produces

```
6708.1717,07/15/2015,6708.3
3352.130000000,07/15/2015,3352
6708.1717,07/15/2015,6708.31
```

Comment: Thank you Glenn! This works.  Just starting to learn awk, and it looks very powerful.